# Conditional Counting Across Tables in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am analyzing the effects of pairwise gene interactions (>300K) on fruit fly behavior and have run into an issue. I would like to count how often certain pairs of gene states (i.e., alleles) occur across my 177 lines.

Some play tables:

```
state1 <-c("A","B","C","A","B","A")
state2 <- c("B","C","D","D","D","C")

df1 <- data.frame(state1,state2)

state <- c("A","B","C","D")
line_1 <- c(0,0,2,0)
line_2 <- c(0,0,0,2)
line_3 <- c(2,2,2,0)
line_4 <- c(0,2,2,2)
line_5 <- c(2,0,0,0)

df2 <- data.frame(state,line_1,line_2,line_3,line_4,line_5, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I am hoping to get an output that returns the number of lines with each state combination (state1=0 and state2=0, state1=0 and state2=2, state1=2 and state2=0, state1=2 and state2=2) and the lines with each of those combinations:

```
> resultdf
  state1 state2 state10state20 state10state22 state12state20 state12state22       lines00       lines02       lines20       lines22
1      A      B              1              1              2              1        line_1,line_2 line_4        line_5        line_3
2      B      C              1              2              0              2        line_5 line_1,line_2            NA line_3,line_4
3      C      D              1              0              2              2        line_5            NA line_1,line_3 line_2,line_4
4      A      D              1              1              2              1        line_1        line_4 line_3,line_5        line_2
5      B      D              2              1              1              1  line_1,line_5        line_2        line_3        line_4
6      A      C              0              2              1              2            NA line_1,line_4        line_5 line_2,line_3
```

I started to look into for loops and if statements but found that R does other things better. I am a novice in R (and coding in general) so I wasn't sure where to turn next. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Under `resultdf`, wouldn't `line_2` in the first row be shown under `lines00`?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the error. I tabulated the `resultsdf` by hand and mis-scored that one. I'll change the original post to reflect the correct `resultsdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

first lets create a table of all the gene combinations. (you already have this in df1, but we can automate it like this rather than hard code):

```
com = combn(unique(df2$state), 2)
```

Now a few helper functions that test for each possible combinations of states

```
both_true    = function(x)  x[1,] &  x[2,]
neither_true = function(x) !x[1,] & !x[2,]
first_true   = function(x)  x[1,] & !x[2,]
second_true  = function(x) !x[1,] &  x[2,]
```

Another helper function, that uses each of the previous ones and stitches the count of their results together

```
all_pos = function(x) c(
   sum(both_true(x)), 
   sum(neither_true(x)), 
   sum(first_true(x)), 
   sum(second_true(x)))
```

Now we can apply these functions to your data set

```
res = apply(com, 2, function(x) all_pos(df2[df2[,1] %in% x, -1]))
```

And set the column / row names so that we can interpret the output

```
colnames(res) = apply(com, 2, paste0, collapse='')
rownames(res) = c('both', 'neither', 'first', 'second')

res
#         AB AC AD BC BD CD
# both     1  1  0  2  1  1
# neither  2  1  1  2  2  1
# first    1  1  2  0  1  2
# second   1  2  2  1  1  1
```

Similarly to get the line numbers themselves:

```
which_pos = function(x) c(
  paste(which(both_true(x)), collapse=','), 
  paste(which(neither_true(x)), collapse=','), 
  paste(which(first_true(x)), collapse=','), 
  paste(which(second_true(x)), collapse=','))
res2 = apply(com, 2, function(x) which_pos(df2[df2[,1] %in% x, -1]))
colnames(res2) = apply(com, 2, paste0, collapse='')
rownames(res2) = c('both', 'neither', 'first', 'second')
res2
# 
#         AB    AC    AD    BC    BD    CD   
# both    "3"   "3"   ""    "3,4" "4"   "4"  
# neither "1,2" "2"   "1"   "2,5" "1,5" "5"  
# first   "5"   "5"   "3,5" ""    "3"   "1,3"
# second  "4"   "1,4" "2,4" "1"   "2"   "2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Running the code given I get an output table that places all lines in either `both` or `neither`. I also get `colnames` that are in the format `12` `13` `14` instead of `"AB" "AC" "AD"`. Could this be due to my use of `0` and `2` as the states and not `1` and `2`?

Comment: I tested, and I can confirm your problem is because you have factors rather than characters in your data frame.  Use `df2 <- data.frame(state,line_1,line_2,line_3,line_4,line_5, stringsAsFactors = F)` instead and you should be good to go.

Comment: Works great! Now to build this up to my real dataset. Thank you!

Comment: An issue scaling it up to my real dataset. I oversimplified `df2`. There should be three possible values `0` `2` and `-` where `-` should be treated as missing data not contributing to the counts of state pairs. How should the code change to account for this? Should I edit the original post to reflect this?

Comment: I think you should just edit the logical tests in the helper functions, so that they check for exactly what you want them to.  E.g. `function(x)  x[1,]=='2' &  x[2,]=='2'`. If you get stuck, maybe a follow up question is better than changing this one.  Btw still no upvote? any reason?

Comment: The new logical tests work well - my actual dataset is still throwing `NA` in all categories but I am thinking the data class has something to do with it. I put in an upvote. My reputation is such that it is recorded but does not shift the publicly displayed count.

Comment: I think if you are still stuck on this NA issue, perhaps best is to create a new question that includes 1) a minimal subset of your actual data (using e.g. `dput(head(data, n))` to get n lines of actual data. 2) the code you are using from this answer (and a link back to this q&a) 3) the output you are getting, 4) the output you want. It will be easier to solve this additional step if it is presented in a new question like this.  Also, it is generally frowned on to edit a question in a way that renders previous answers incorrect - another reason to do a new question rather than edit this one

Comment: No problem - its also fine to ask follow up questions in comments. If they are easily fixed there and are clearly related to the original q then that's the best way.  Its jyust that you latest issue with NA's is tricky to be sure of the exact problem without more info, hence my suggestion to post a new question.  Its possible that adding `na.rm = TRUE` to the `sum` statements could solve your  issue, but I cant be sure without seeing the real data.